# KOMA-Classes (scrbook, scrreprt, ... ): Disable chapter separation in \listoffigures and \listoftables

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I use `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. Both commands create line breaks for items from different chapters. How can you stop that?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What class are you using? It seems `scrbook` or `scrreprt`; it's important to know.

Comment: I use: scrreprt

Comment: Try `\KOMAoptions{listof=nochaptergap}` in your preamble.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to table 3.20 in the KOMA-Script manual the following snippet added to the preamble will solve the issue

```
\KOMAoptions{listof=nochaptergap}
```

alternatively you can pass this option directly to the koma-documentclass

```
\documentclass[listof=nochaptergap]{scrreprt}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's explained in section 3.16 of the manual of KoMa-Script:

```
\documentclass
 [... other options ...,
  chapteratlists=0pt]{scrreprt}
```