# Remove Gap in Table of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to remove the gap between the figures of different chapters in my `table of figures`. I have a screenshot here:

[image]

Is there some kind of command to disable the gap? I'm not sure what kind of MWE I can give, as its the table of figures in a large document.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I assume you are using `book` class?

Comment: Wouldn't something like this be an MWE? `\documentclass{<insert your class>}\begin{document}\listoftables\chapter{a}\begin{table}\caption{}\end{table}\chapter{b}\begin{table}\caption{}\end{table}\end{document}`

Comment: Also, duplicate of [How to change the line spacing in my list of figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/784) or [Remove spacing between per-chapter figures in LoF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121879) perhaps?

Comment: Duplicate of [Disable chapter separation in \listoffigures and \listoftables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98636) and [Vertical Spacing Between Figure Names from Different Chapters in Table of Figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240226) and [How to change the line spacing in my list of figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51880)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for `book.cls`

The gap is introduced by the `\chapter` command (actually \@chapter`), using

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
```

each time a new chapter is set up, i.e. vertical space (the gap!) is set to the relevant `.lof` or `.lot` file.

This can be patched out with `\xpatchcmd{}`, replacing the commands in `\@chapter` with 'nothing'.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}{}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Dummy figure}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is a `tocloft` based solution too

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a KOMA-Script class (`scrbook` or `srcreprt`) you can use the option `listof=nochaptergap` to disable the gap:

```
\documentclass[listof=nochaptergap]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\chapter{First}
\captionof{figure}{Eine Abbildung}
\captionof{figure}{Eine zweite Abbildung}

\chapter{Second}
\captionof{figure}{Eine Abbildung im zweiten Kapitel}
\end{document}
```

[image]