# How to change the space in list of figure?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

This is my code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,up,textfont=up]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{titletoc}%
%listoffigures
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
  \null\hfill\textbf{\normalsize\listfigurename}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
  \vspace{20pt}

    \@starttoc{lof}%
}
\titlecontents{figure}
  [2.5cm]
  {}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \makebox[2.4cm][l]{Gambar~\thecontentslabel}%
    }%
  }
  {\hspace{-1.7cm}}
  {\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures%
}
\chapter{kkk}
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is the first}
\end{figure}
\chapter{LLLLLLLLLLLL}
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is the Second}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{I want to make the space in list of figure is 18pt.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{For example, I want the space \textbf{Gambar 1.1} to \textbf{Gambar 2.1} is same with space \textbf{Gambar 2.1} to \textbf{Gambar 2.2}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{That's mean, that space for each \textbf{Gambar} is same}
\end{figure}
\chapter{LLLLLLLLLLLL}
\begin{figure}
\caption{But, for case \textbf{Gambar 2.3} and this part, I want to make the space only 12pt. Because \textbf{Gambar 2.3} have 2 line in one caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I am sorry, but I have no clue, what you are asking for.  Please edit your question and add more details, especially a clear description, what you want to achieve.  (If you have problems to find the right words, take a pencil, make a sketch, make a photo and upload that as help.)  Where did you get that code from your MWE?  The PDF produced from your example looks correct to me.

Comment: It's not correct. The space is not whay I want. Please run the code

Comment: sorry, that I wanted to help, but was not able to understand your question. I am attempted to downvote your question.  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `titlesec` and `titletoc` together with a KOMA-Script class. These classes load package `tocbasic` automatically. So you can use package `tocbasic` to change the layout of TOC and lists like LOF and LOT.

```latex
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  %twoside,% default
  listof=entryprefix,
  listof=nochaptergap,
  indonesian
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage{scrextend}% not needed for this example

\addtokomafont{caption}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\captionformat}{\ }
\setcapindent{0pt}

\BeforeTOCHead[lof]{%
  \renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}%
  \addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\rmfamily}%
  \renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=\baselineskip,afterindent=false,afterskip=20pt]{chapter}%
}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=18pt
]{default}{figure}
\makeatletter\renewcommand\@dotsep{2.5}\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{kkk}
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is the first}
\end{figure}
\chapter{LLLLLLLLLLLL}
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is the Second}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{I want to make the space in list of figure is 18pt.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{For example, I want the space \textbf{Gambar 1.1} to \textbf{Gambar 2.1} is same with space \textbf{Gambar 2.1} to \textbf{Gambar 2.2}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{That's mean, that space for each \textbf{Gambar} is same}
\end{figure}
\chapter{LLLLLLLLLLLL}
\begin{figure}
\caption{But, for case \textbf{Gambar 2.3} and this part, I want to make the space only 12pt. Because \textbf{Gambar 2.3} have 2 line in one caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Suggestion using the MWE from the question and the **standard class `book`** (because of a comment of the OP):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,up,textfont=up]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\usepackage{titletoc}%
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
  \null\hfill\textbf{\normalsize\listfigurename}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
  \vspace{20pt}

    \@starttoc{lof}%
}}
\titlecontents{figure}
  [2.5cm]
  {\addvspace{18pt}}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \makebox[2.4cm][l]{Gambar~\thecontentslabel}%
    }%
  }
  {\hspace{-1.7cm}}
  {\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275577:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{kkk}
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is the first}
\end{figure}
\chapter{LLLLLLLLLLLL}
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is the Second}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{I want to make the space in list of figure is 18pt.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{For example, I want the space \textbf{Gambar 1.1} to \textbf{Gambar 2.1} is same with space \textbf{Gambar 2.1} to \textbf{Gambar 2.2}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{That's mean, that space for each \textbf{Gambar} is same}
\end{figure}
\chapter{LLLLLLLLLLLL}
\begin{figure}
\caption{But, for case \textbf{Gambar 2.3} and this part, I want to make the space only 12pt. Because \textbf{Gambar 2.3} have 2 line in one caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my latex. I have copy your code, but I get an error "Undefined Control Sequence \DeclareTOCStyleEntry".

Comment: Which KOMA-Script version do you use? `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` was introduced in version 3.20 in 2016. Current version is 3.27.

Comment: I use the 2012 version. Any solution for this version?

Comment: @Eddy update to the actual version of KOMA-Script?

Comment: @Eddy I do not have such an outdated version. But I think, option `listof=nochaptergap` should work anyway. So you can remove the additional space between entries of different chapters. Maybe the first mandatory argument of `\titlecontents{figure}` (the empty one in your code) can bei used to add vertical space before each figure entry. You should mention in your questions that you use such an old TeX version and outdated classes and packages.

Comment: @esdd. Ya, the option listof=nochaptergap is work. But the space for the line in one caption not yet. I'll try to mention it. Thank you.

Comment: @Jan do you have solution for old versin?

Comment: If `\titlecontents{figure}[...]{\addvspace{18pt}}{...}{...}{...}` does not work with the code in your question then maybe your `titletoc` version is outdated too.

Comment: @esdd how to make this code work in book class not scrbook class?

Comment: @Eddy I have added a suggestion for `book`. But I do not know, if it works with your really very old TeX distribution.

Comment: @esdd if you don't mind, I want to try it.

Comment: @esdd thank you very much. It work with my TeX.