# My page number widened

Tags: page-numbering

I've a problem with my page number. This is my code

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand {\fncyfront }{%
\fancyhead[RO]{{}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{}
\fancyhead[LE]{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth }{0pt }}
\newcommand {\fncymain }{%
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\pagestyle{empty}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{1pt}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=215mm,top=3cm,left=4cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Gambar}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabel}

%\renewcommand{\refname}{Daftar Pustaka}
%\renewcommand{\bibliname}{Daftar Pustaka}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{mdframed} \newmdenv[]{kotak} %membuat kotak
\newenvironment{subs}
  {\adjustwidth{0.935cm}{0pt}}
  {\endadjustwidth}
  \newenvironment{subs2}
    {\adjustwidth{1.28cm}{0pt}}
    {\endadjustwidth}
% Membuat seluruh tulisan menjadi Times New Roman. 
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{mathtools} \newcommand
\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}} %penomoran equation
\usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{mathrsfs}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB}                % mengubah "Chapter" jadi "BAB"
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{            %pengaturan awal

{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\center \MakeUppercase{\large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}
%\chapapp\space memunculkan kata "Bab"
\par\nobreak
\vskip 6\p@ % Mengatur jarak antara "Bab 1" dan "Pendahuluan"
\fi
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \uppercase{\bfseries #1\par\nobreak} %Bagian ini memunculkan judul bab
\vskip 30\p@ % Mengatur jarak antara "Bab 1" dengan "Teks"
}}
%

\makeatother                            %pengaturan akhir
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\bf\normalsize}{\makebox[1.78em][l]{\thesection}}{1ex}{}{}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bf\normalsize}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bf\normalsize}
% Mengatur spacing section

\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{24pt}{6pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{24pt}{6pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
{0pt}{24pt}{6pt}
% Untuk mengkustomisasi margin
\usepackage{scrextend}
% Digunakan untuk mengatur caption dalam dokumen.
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,up,textfont=up]{caption}
% Untuk menghapus titik dua (colon)
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
% Redefinition of ToC command to get centered heading
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ISI}\cleardoublepage\null\vspace{-12pt}\hfill\textbf{\large\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
  \vspace{30pt}
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{eqparbox} %membuat spasi chapter rata

\usepackage{titletoc}%
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\vspace{12pt}\bfseries}% <above-code>
  {\eqmakebox[TC][l]{\chaptername~\thecontentslabel }\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\hfill\contentspage}[\vspace{0pt}]

  \titlecontents{section}[27mm]   
    {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont} 
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{24pt}}{}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}{\contentspage}}  

  \titlecontents{subsection}[38mm]   
    {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont} 
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{30pt}}{}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}{\contentspage}}  
%listoffigures
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
\cleardoublepage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
  \null\vspace{-24pt}\hfill\textbf{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont\listfigurename}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
  \vspace{20pt}

    \@starttoc{lof}%
}}

\titlecontents{figure}
  [2.5cm]
  {\addvspace{12pt}}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \makebox[2.4cm][l]{Gambar~\thecontentslabel}%
    }%
  }
  {\hspace{-1.7cm}}
  {\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275577:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}{}{}{}
\makeatother

%listoftables
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\cleardoublepage{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
  \null\hfill\textbf{\large\listtablename}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
  \vspace{20pt}

    \@starttoc{lot}%
}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\cleardoublepage{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
  \null\hfill\textbf{\large\listfigurename}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
  \vspace{20pt}

    \@starttoc{lof}%
}}
\titlecontents{table}
  [2.5cm]
  {\addvspace{12pt}}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \makebox[2.4cm][l]{Tabel~\thecontentslabel}%
    }%
  }
  {\hspace{-1.7cm}}
  {\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{abstract}{
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}%
    \bfseries\abstractname
  \end{center}}%
  {\vfill}

  \usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\fncyfront
\frontmatter
 \newgeometry{top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm} 

 \begin{titlepage}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN SAMPUL}                                                             %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
\includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                        %environment akhir gambar
  \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                            %memulai rata tengah
\fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {SOLUSI NUMERIK MODEL ALIRAN MASSA\\DALAM SISTEM KULTIVASI \textit{OPEN POND RACEWAYS} PADA SAWAH ALGA}\\
    % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic 
 \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm 
 \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
 \vspace{3.5cm}

 \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{EDDY ISWARDI\\G 201 16 043}}\\

  \vspace{5cm}
\fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI MATEMATIKA JURUSAN MATEMATIKA\\
 FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
 UNIVERSITAS TADULAKO}}\\
\fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}
 \end{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{2}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN JUDUL}
 \begin{titlepage}
 \cleardoublepage
 \pagestyle{fancy}

                                                                    %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
\includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                        %environment akhir gambar
  \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                            %memulai rata tengah
\fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {SOLUSI NUMERIK MODEL ALIRAN MASSA\\DALAM SISTEM KULTIVASI \textit{OPEN POND RACEWAYS} PADA SAWAH ALGA}\\
    % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic 
 \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm 
 \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
 \vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont { \textbf{Diajukan untuk memenuhi salah satu persyaratan\\
dalam menyelesaikan Program Sarjana Strata Satu (S1)\\
Program Studi Matematika pada Jurusan Matematika FMIPA Universitas\\
Tadulako\\}}
 \vspace{1cm}
 \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{EDDY ISWARDI\\G 201 16 043}}\\

  \vspace{5cm}
\fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI MATEMATIKA JURUSAN MATEMATIKA\\
 FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
 UNIVERSITAS TADULAKO}}\\
\fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}

 \end{titlepage}

 \restoregeometry


 \setcounter{page}{3}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN PERSETUJUAN PEMBIMBING}

 \begin{center}
 {\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PERSETUJUAN PEMBIMBING}}}
 \end{center}
 \vspace{36pt}
 \begin{flushleft}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% local to flushleft
 \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}@{:\space}p{11cm}}
 Judul&\textbf{Solusi Numerik Model Aliran Massa dalam Sistem Kultivasi \textit{Open Pond Raceways} pada Sawah Alga}\\[1\baselineskip]
 Nama&\textbf{Eddy Iswardi}\\[1\baselineskip]
 Stambuk&\textbf{G20116043}\\
 \end{tabular}\\
 \vspace{24pt}
 Telah diperiksa dan disetujui untuk diajukan pada Seminar Hasil\\
 \vspace{24pt}
 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{6cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{6cm}}
 &Palu, 15 Desember 2019\\
 Mengetahui,\\
 Ketua Jurusan Matematika&Pembimbing\\
 FMIPA Universitas Tadulako \\[3\baselineskip]
 \underline{\textbf{Junaidi, S.Si, M.Si, Ph.D}}&\underline{\textbf{Dra. Rina Ratianingsih, M.Si}} \\
 NIP. 197402262000121001& NIP. 196608111995032001\\
 \end{tabular*}
 \end{flushleft}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ISI}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures%


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
{\cleardoublepage%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoftables%
}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\cleardoublepage
\fncymain
\mainmatter

\pagestyle{fancy}
\onehalfspacing
\chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{Latar Belakang}
\begin{subs}
Fenomena pemanasan global (\textit{global warming}) dan menipisnya sumber energi dari minyak dan gas bumi membuat pemerintah merumuskan Kebijakan Energi Nasional untuk menggali sumber energi alternatif, energi terbarukan termasuk energi kelautan yang berbasis mikroalga (Suryanto, 2009). Disisi lain, Indonesia sebagai negara kepulauan memiliki biodiversitas perairan  melimpah yang potensial untuk dikembangkan sebagai sumber energi terbarukan yang bersumber dari wilayah perairan. \vspace{\baselineskip}\label{b1p1}

\noindent Dengan kandungan minyak lipid lebih dari 30\% (Chisti \textit{dalam}  Hadiyanto, 2010), mikroalga sangat berpotensi untuk digunakan sebagai sumber energi alternatif biodiesel. Penelitian sebelumnya yang menyatakan bahwa mikroalga mempunyai produktivitas 200 kali lebih banyak dibandingkan sumber nabati lainnya (Hadiyanto,2010), memperlihatkan bahwa ketersediaan bahan baku biodiesel dari mikroalga sangat terjamin. Tingkat produksi biodiesel yang dihasilkan dari  pengolahan mikroalga pada lahan seluas 4.5 juta hektar mampu menghasilkan biodiesel yang dapat mengganti seluruh kebutuhan solar di Amerika Serikat. Hadiyanto (2010) menyebutkan bahwa luas lahan ini hanya 1\% dari total lahan yang sekarang digunakan untuk lahan pertanian dan padang rumput (sekitar 0.5 milliar ha).\\\label{b1p2}

\noindent Pengelolaan budidaya mikroalga dapat dilakukan dengan beberapa cara salah satunya adalah sistem kultivasi dalam kolam. Salah satu jenis kolam kultivasi yang biasa digunakan adalah \textit{Open Pond Raceways} (Kolam Sirkuit). Pada sistem kolam sirkuit, bibit mikroalga, media tumbuh (pada umumya air), dan nutrisi dicampurkan secara langsung dalam kolam sehingga aliran campuran tersebut mengalir menyerupai aliran sirkuit. Aliran air dilengkapi pula dengan sistem pemompaan, sehingga mikroalga dan nutrisi tetap dapat tercampur dan tidak terjadi pengendapan mikroalga (Hadiyanto dan Azim, 2012). Kolam sirkuit inilah yang digunakan sebagai kolam atau sawah mikroalga\\\label{b1p3}

\noindent Pada kolam atau sawah mikroalga terdapat sebuat kincir (\textit{paddle wheel}) yang berfungsi sebagai penggerak aliran. Pada bagian tengah kolam terdapat sebuah dinding melintang sebagai pembatas kedua sisi lintasan dalam kolam. Pada bagian dasar kolam terdapat pula cekungan yang disebut sebagai sump.\\ \label{b1p4}

\noindent Aliran  massa dalam sistem kultivasikolam sirkuit menjadikan distribusi mikroalga pada suatu arah aliran mengalami perubahan dari keadaaan awalnya. Oleh karena itu, perlu ditinjau bagaimana aliran massa dalam sistem kultivasi tersebut selama berlangsungnya pertumbuhan mikroalga.\\

\noindent Metode numerik adalah teknik matematika yang digunakan untuk memecahkan masalah matematika yang tidak dapat dipecahkan atau sulit untuk diselesaikan secara analitis (Gilat dan Subraham, 2013). Beberapa metode numerik yang umum dipakai adalah  Metode iterasi \textit{Jacobi} dan metode iterasi \textit{Gauss-Seidel} yang digunakan sebagai solusi sistem persamaan linear, metode interpolasi dan regresi yang digunakan untuk pencocokan kurva, dan metode beda hingga yang digunakan untuk penyelesaia persamaan diferensial. \\

\noindent Penelitian ini menawarkan perancangan model  matematika aliran massa dalam sistem kultivasi kolam sirkuit pada sawah alga. Model matematika tersebut dibangun berdasarkan fakta-fakta serta asumsi-asumsi yang selanjutnya akan diselesaikan secara dinamik dan dibandingkan secara numerik menggunakan metode beda hingga. Metode tersebut menggunakan perbedaan hingga yang disusun dengan tujuan mengurangi penyelesaian sistem persamaan aljabar. Penampang  sawah mikroalga tampak atas digambarkan pada Gambar 1.1. Arah panah menunjukkan arah aliran (Hadiyanto dan Azim,2012) :
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
 \fbox{%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr9cm-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{gambar1.png}
    \caption{Geometri Kolam Sirkuit} \label{bab1g1}
   \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{subs}
\section{Rumusan Masalah}
\begin{subs}
Berdasarkan latar belakang diatas maka permasalahan dalam penelitian ini dirumuskan sebagai berikut
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item Bagaimana model matematika dari aliran massa dalam sistem kultivasi kolam sirkuit pada mikroalga?
\item Bagaimana skema numerik numerik model matematika dari aliran fluida tersebut?
\end{enumerate} 
\end{subs}
\section{Tujuan Penelitian}
\begin{subs}
Adapun tujuan dari dilakukannya penelitian ini yaitu :
\begin{enumerate}
\item Mendapatkan model matematika ari aliran massa dalam sistem kultivasi kolam sirkuit pada mikroalga
\item Mendapatkan skema numerik model matematika dari aliran fluida tersebut
\end{enumerate}
\end{subs}
\section{Manfaat Penelitian}
\begin{subs}
Manfaat yang diharapkan dari hasil penelitian ini yaitu.
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item Sebagai referensi pemodelan matematika dalam bidang pertanian mikroalga
\item Sebagai dukungan terhadap pengembangan ilmu matematika terapan
\end{enumerate}
\end{subs}
\section{Asumsi Penelitian}
\begin{subs}
Adapun asumsi yang dikemukakan dalam penelitian ini antara lain :
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item Mikroalga, nutrisi dan air larutan tercampur secara homogen.
\item Faktor energi yang timbul akibat aktivitas  disekitar kolam diabaikan, baik faktor suhu maupun energi dari sistem kultivasi.
\item Fluida bersifat dinamis dan \textit{incompressible}.
\item Aliran bersifat \textit{Unsteady State}.
\item Penelitian di fokuskan pada satu fase pertumbuhan mikrolga (fase stagnan)
\item Faktor iklim diabaikan
\item Penelitian ini difokuskan pada aliran lapisan batas yang terletak disekitar titik stagnasi bawah $x=0$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{subs}
\section{Batasan Penelitian}
\begin{subs}
Penelitian ini memiliki beberapa batasan sebagai berikut :
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item \textit{Sump} pada sistem sirkuit tidak digunakan, model hanya mengkaji sistem sirkuit aliran alga tanpa sump
\item Hanya terdapat satu dinding pembatas di tengah sawah mikroalga yang memanjang secara horizontal
\end{enumerate}
\end{subs}
\end{document}
```

the result is like this[image]
the position of page number should be in red are, not in blue.[image]

How to fix it? Because someone need a simple code, this the simple code

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand {\fncyfront }{%
\fancyhead[RO]{{}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{}
\fancyhead[LE]{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth }{0pt }}
\newcommand {\fncymain }{%
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\pagestyle{empty}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{1pt}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=215mm,top=3cm,left=4cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}



%\renewcommand{\refname}{Daftar Pustaka}
%\renewcommand{\bibliname}{Daftar Pustaka}


\usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{mathrsfs}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB}                % mengubah "Chapter" jadi "BAB"
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{            %pengaturan awal

{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\center \MakeUppercase{\large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}
%\chapapp\space memunculkan kata "Bab"
\par\nobreak
\vskip 6\p@ % Mengatur jarak antara "Bab 1" dan "Pendahuluan"
\fi
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \uppercase{\bfseries #1\par\nobreak} %Bagian ini memunculkan judul bab
\vskip 30\p@ % Mengatur jarak antara "Bab 1" dengan "Teks"
}}
%

\usepackage{tocbasic}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
% Redefinition of ToC command to get centered heading
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ISI}\cleardoublepage\null\vspace{-12pt}\hfill\textbf{\large\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
  \vspace{30pt}
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{eqparbox} %membuat spasi chapter rata

\usepackage{titletoc}%
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\vspace{12pt}\bfseries}% <above-code>
  {\eqmakebox[TC][l]{\chaptername~\thecontentslabel }\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\hfill\contentspage}[\vspace{0pt}]

  \titlecontents{section}[27mm]   
    {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont} 
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{24pt}}{}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}{\contentspage}}  

  \titlecontents{subsection}[38mm]   
    {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont} 
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{30pt}}{}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}{\contentspage}}  
%listoffigures
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
\cleardoublepage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
  \null\vspace{-24pt}\hfill\textbf{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont\listfigurename}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
  \vspace{20pt}

    \@starttoc{lof}%
}}

\titlecontents{figure}
  [2.5cm]
  {\addvspace{12pt}}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \makebox[2.4cm][l]{Gambar~\thecontentslabel}%
    }%
  }
  {\hspace{-1.7cm}}
  {\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275577:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}{}{}{}
\makeatother

%listoftables
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\cleardoublepage{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
  \null\hfill\textbf{\large\listtablename}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
  \vspace{20pt}

    \@starttoc{lot}%
}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\cleardoublepage{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
  \null\hfill\textbf{\large\listfigurename}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
  \vspace{20pt}

    \@starttoc{lof}%
}}
\titlecontents{table}
  [2.5cm]
  {\addvspace{12pt}}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \makebox[2.4cm][l]{Tabel~\thecontentslabel}%
    }%
  }
  {\hspace{-1.7cm}}
  {\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{abstract}{
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}%
    \bfseries\abstractname
  \end{center}}%
  {\vfill}

  \usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\fncyfront
\frontmatter
 \newgeometry{top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm} 

 \begin{titlepage}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN SAMPUL}                                                             %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
\includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                        %environment akhir gambar
  \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                            %memulai rata tengah
\fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {SOLUSI NUMERIK MODEL ALIRAN MASSA\\DALAM SISTEM KULTIVASI \textit{OPEN POND RACEWAYS} PADA SAWAH ALGA}\\
    % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic 
 \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm 
 \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
 \vspace{3.5cm}

 \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{EDDY ISWARDI\\G 201 16 043}}\\

  \vspace{5cm}
\fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI MATEMATIKA JURUSAN MATEMATIKA\\
 FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
 UNIVERSITAS TADULAKO}}\\
\fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}
 \end{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{2}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN JUDUL}
 \begin{titlepage}
 \cleardoublepage
 \pagestyle{fancy}

                                                                    %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
\includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                        %environment akhir gambar
  \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                            %memulai rata tengah
\fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {SOLUSI NUMERIK MODEL ALIRAN MASSA\\DALAM SISTEM KULTIVASI \textit{OPEN POND RACEWAYS} PADA SAWAH ALGA}\\
    % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic 
 \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm 
 \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
 \vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont { \textbf{Diajukan untuk memenuhi salah satu persyaratan\\
dalam menyelesaikan Program Sarjana Strata Satu (S1)\\
Program Studi Matematika pada Jurusan Matematika FMIPA Universitas\\
Tadulako\\}}
 \vspace{1cm}
 \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{EDDY ISWARDI\\G 201 16 043}}\\

  \vspace{5cm}
\fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI MATEMATIKA JURUSAN MATEMATIKA\\
 FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
 UNIVERSITAS TADULAKO}}\\
\fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}

 \end{titlepage}

 \restoregeometry

\fncymain
\mainmatter

\pagestyle{fancy}
\onehalfspacing
\chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{Latar Belakang}
\begin{subs}
Fenomena pemanasan global (\textit{global warming}) dan menipisnya sumber energi dari minyak dan gas bumi membuat pemerintah merumuskan Kebijakan Energi Nasional untuk menggali sumber energi alternatif, energi terbarukan termasuk energi kelautan yang berbasis mikroalga (Suryanto, 2009). Disisi lain, Indonesia sebagai negara kepulauan memiliki biodiversitas perairan  melimpah yang potensial untuk dikembangkan sebagai sumber energi terbarukan yang bersumber dari wilayah perairan. \vspace{\baselineskip}\label{b1p1}
\newpage
\section{Rumusan Masalah}
\begin{subs}
Berdasarkan latar belakang diatas maka permasalahan dalam penelitian ini dirumuskan sebagai berikut
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item Bagaimana model matematika dari aliran massa dalam sistem kultivasi kolam sirkuit pada mikroalga?
\item Bagaimana skema numerik numerik model matematika dari aliran fluida tersebut?
\end{enumerate} 
\end{subs}
\section{Tujuan Penelitian}
\begin{subs}
Adapun tujuan dari dilakukannya penelitian ini yaitu :
\begin{enumerate}
\item Mendapatkan model matematika ari aliran massa dalam sistem kultivasi kolam sirkuit pada mikroalga
\item Mendapatkan skema numerik model matematika dari aliran fluida tersebut
\end{enumerate}
\end{subs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `fancyhdr` *after* `geometry`

Comment: Could you please try to make your example more minimal? Ther is a lot of code that is most likely not at all related to the issue you describe.

Comment: @egreg do you mean package `geometry`? it's not work

Comment: @leandriis, the minimal one in the last

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want the `plain` page style for the front matter and a style with only  the page numbers for the main matter (except on the first page of chapters). It is very simple to do that with `titleps` which is very simple to load, adding the `pagestyles` option to the loading of titlesec. So I defined a `\newpagestyle{mainps}`  and loaded it at the beginning of the main matter.

*Unrelated*: I don't understand why you didn't  redefine the chapter headings layout via `titlesec` since you do it for sections and (sub)subsections.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, demo]{book}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{pslatex}%
    \usepackage{setspace}

    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{1pt}
    \usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=215mm,top=3cm,left=4cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Gambar}
    \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabel}

    %\renewcommand{\refname}{Daftar Pustaka}
    %\renewcommand{\bibliname}{Daftar Pustaka}

    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \usepackage{mdframed} \newmdenv[]{kotak} %membuat kotak
    \newenvironment{subs}
      {\adjustwidth{0.935cm}{0pt}}
      {\endadjustwidth}
      \newenvironment{subs2}
        {\adjustwidth{1.28cm}{0pt}}
        {\endadjustwidth}
    % Membuat seluruh tulisan menjadi Times New Roman.
    \usepackage{pslatex}
    \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{mathtools} \newcommand
    \numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}} %penomoran equation
    \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \hyphenpenalty=10000
    \hbadness=10000
    \tolerance=1
    \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB}                % mengubah "Chapter" jadi "BAB"
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{            %pengaturan awal

    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \center \MakeUppercase{\large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}
    %\chapapp\space memunculkan kata "Bab"
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 6\p@ % Mengatur jarak antara "Bab 1" dan "Pendahuluan"
    \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \large \uppercase{\bfseries #1\par\nobreak} %Bagian ini memunculkan judul bab
    \vskip 30\p@ % Mengatur jarak antara "Bab 1" dengan "Teks"
    }}
    %
    \makeatother                            %pengaturan akhir
    \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

    \titleformat{\section}{\bf\normalsize}{\makebox[1.78em][l]{\thesection}}{1ex}{}{}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\bf\normalsize}
    \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bf\normalsize}
    % Mengatur spacing section

    \titlespacing*{\section}
    {0pt}{24pt}{6pt}
    \titlespacing*{\subsection}
    {0pt}{24pt}{6pt}
    \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
    {0pt}{24pt}{6pt}
    % Untuk mengkustomisasi margin

    \newpagestyle{mainps}{%
    \setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
}


    \usepackage{scrextend}
    % Digunakan untuk mengatur caption dalam dokumen.
    \usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,up,textfont=up]{caption}
    % Untuk menghapus titik dua (colon)
    \captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
    \captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space}
    \usepackage{tocbasic}

    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
    % Redefinition of ToC command to get centered heading
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ISI}\cleardoublepage\null\vspace{-12pt}\hfill\textbf{\large\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
      \vspace{30pt}
      \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
    \makeatother

    \usepackage{eqparbox} %membuat spasi chapter rata

    \usepackage{titletoc}%
    \titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
      [0pt]% <left>
      {\vspace{12pt}\bfseries}% <above-code>
      {\eqmakebox[TC][l]{\chaptername~\thecontentslabel }\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
      {}% <numberless-entry-format>
      {\hfill\contentspage}[\vspace{0pt}]

      \titlecontents{section}[27mm]
        {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont}
        {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{24pt}}{}
        {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}{\contentspage}}

      \titlecontents{subsection}[38mm]
        {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont}
        {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{30pt}}{}
        {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}{\contentspage}}
    %listoffigures
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
    \cleardoublepage
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\listoffigures{{%
      \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
      \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
      \null\vspace{-24pt}\hfill\textbf{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont\listfigurename}\hfill\null\par
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
      \vspace{20pt}

        \@starttoc{lof}%
    }}

    \titlecontents{figure}
      [2.5cm]
      {\addvspace{12pt}}
      {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
          \makebox[2.4cm][l]{Gambar~\thecontentslabel}%
        }%
      }
      {\hspace{-1.7cm}}
      {\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}

    % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275577:
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
      \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    }{}{}{}
    \makeatother

    %listoftables
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
    \cleardoublepage{}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\listoftables{%
      \null\hfill\textbf{\large\listtablename}\hfill\null\par
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
      \vspace{20pt}

        \@starttoc{lot}%
    }
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
    \cleardoublepage{}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\listoffigures{{%
      \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
      \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
      \null\hfill\textbf{\large\listfigurename}\hfill\null\par
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
      \vspace{20pt}

        \@starttoc{lof}%
    }}
    \titlecontents{table}
      [2.5cm]
      {\addvspace{12pt}}
      {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
          \makebox[2.4cm][l]{Tabel~\thecontentslabel}%
        }%
      }
      {\hspace{-1.7cm}}
      {\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
      \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    }{}{}{}
    \makeatother

    \newenvironment{abstract}{
      \vspace*{\fill}
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries\abstractname
      \end{center}}%
      {\vfill}

      \usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
      \addbibresource{references.bib}
    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    %\fncyfront
    \frontmatter
     \newgeometry{top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm}

     \begin{titlepage}
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN SAMPUL}                                                             %Menghilangkan nomor halaman
     \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
    \includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                            %environment akhir gambar
      \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                                %memulai rata tengah
    \fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {SOLUSI NUMERIK MODEL ALIRAN MASSA\\DALAM SISTEM KULTIVASI \textit{OPEN POND RACEWAYS} PADA SAWAH ALGA}\\
        % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic
     \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm
     \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
     \vspace{3.5cm}

     \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{EDDY ISWARDI\\G 201 16 043}}\\

      \vspace{5cm}
    \fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI MATEMATIKA JURUSAN MATEMATIKA\\
     FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
     UNIVERSITAS TADULAKO}}\\
    \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}
     \end{titlepage}
    \setcounter{page}{2}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN JUDUL}
     \begin{titlepage}
     \cleardoublepage                                                                   %Menghilangkan nomor halaman
     \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
    \includegraphics[width=3.2cm,height=3.5cm]{logo.png}\\                                      %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                            %environment akhir gambar
      \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                                %memulai rata tengah
    \fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {SOLUSI NUMERIK MODEL ALIRAN MASSA\\DALAM SISTEM KULTIVASI \textit{OPEN POND RACEWAYS} PADA SAWAH ALGA}\\
        % \textbf=bold dan \textit=italic
     \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                             %spasi vertikal sejauh 1.5cm
     \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{SKRIPSI}}\\
     \vspace{1cm}
    \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont { \textbf{Diajukan untuk memenuhi salah satu persyaratan\\
    dalam menyelesaikan Program Sarjana Strata Satu (S1)\\
    Program Studi Matematika pada Jurusan Matematika FMIPA Universitas\\
    Tadulako\\}}
     \vspace{1cm}
     \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{EDDY ISWARDI\\G 201 16 043}}\\

      \vspace{5cm}
    \fontsize{14}{12pt}\selectfont{ \textbf{PROGRAM STUDI MATEMATIKA JURUSAN MATEMATIKA\\
     FAKULTAS MATEMATIKA DAN ILMU PENGETAHUAN ALAM\\
     UNIVERSITAS TADULAKO}}\\
    \fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont {\textbf{DESEMBER, 2019}}

     \end{titlepage}

     \restoregeometry

     \setcounter{page}{3}
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN PERSETUJUAN PEMBIMBING}

     \begin{center}
     {\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PERSETUJUAN PEMBIMBING}}}
     \end{center}
     \vspace{36pt}
     \begin{flushleft}
     \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% local to flushleft
     \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}@{:\space}p{11cm}}
     Judul&\textbf{Solusi Numerik Model Aliran Massa dalam Sistem Kultivasi \textit{Open Pond Raceways} pada Sawah Alga}\\[1\baselineskip]
     Nama&\textbf{Eddy Iswardi}\\[1\baselineskip]
     Stambuk&\textbf{G20116043}\\
     \end{tabular}\\
     \vspace{24pt}
     Telah diperiksa dan disetujui untuk diajukan pada Seminar Hasil\\
     \vspace{24pt}
     \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{6cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{6cm}}
     &Palu, 15 Desember 2019\\
     Mengetahui,\\
     Ketua Jurusan Matematika&Pembimbing\\
     FMIPA Universitas Tadulako \\[3\baselineskip]
     \underline{\textbf{Junaidi, S.Si, M.Si, Ph.D}}&\underline{\textbf{Dra. Rina Ratianingsih, M.Si}} \\
     NIP. 197402262000121001& NIP. 196608111995032001\\
     \end{tabular*}
     \end{flushleft}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ISI}
    \tableofcontents

    \newpage
    \cleardoublepage
    \listoffigures%

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    {\cleardoublepage%
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoftables%
    }
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
    \cleardoublepage

    \mainmatter
    \onehalfspacing
    \pagestyle{mainps}
    \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \section{Latar Belakang}
    \begin{subs}
    Fenomena pemanasan global (\textit{global warming}) dan menipisnya sumber energi dari minyak dan gas bumi membuat pemerintah merumuskan Kebijakan Energi Nasional untuk menggali sumber energi alternatif, energi terbarukan termasuk energi kelautan yang berbasis mikroalga (Suryanto, 2009). Disisi lain, Indonesia sebagai negara kepulauan memiliki biodiversitas perairan melimpah yang potensial untuk dikembangkan sebagai sumber energi terbarukan yang bersumber dari wilayah perairan. \vspace{\baselineskip}\label{b1p1}

    \noindent Dengan kandungan minyak lipid lebih dari 30\% (Chisti \textit{dalam} Hadiyanto, 2010), mikroalga sangat berpotensi untuk digunakan sebagai sumber energi alternatif biodiesel. Penelitian sebelumnya yang menyatakan bahwa mikroalga mempunyai produktivitas 200 kali lebih banyak dibandingkan sumber nabati lainnya (Hadiyanto,2010), memperlihatkan bahwa ketersediaan bahan baku biodiesel dari mikroalga sangat terjamin. Tingkat produksi biodiesel yang dihasilkan dari pengolahan mikroalga pada lahan seluas 4.5 juta hektar mampu menghasilkan biodiesel yang dapat mengganti seluruh kebutuhan solar di Amerika Serikat. Hadiyanto (2010) menyebutkan bahwa luas lahan ini hanya 1\% dari total lahan yang sekarang digunakan untuk lahan pertanian dan padang rumput (sekitar 0.5 milliar ha).\\\label{b1p2}

    \noindent Pengelolaan budidaya mikroalga dapat dilakukan dengan beberapa cara salah satunya adalah sistem kultivasi dalam kolam. Salah satu jenis kolam kultivasi yang biasa digunakan adalah \textit{Open Pond Raceways} (Kolam Sirkuit). Pada sistem kolam sirkuit, bibit mikroalga, media tumbuh (pada umumya air), dan nutrisi dicampurkan secara langsung dalam kolam sehingga aliran campuran tersebut mengalir menyerupai aliran sirkuit. Aliran air dilengkapi pula dengan sistem pemompaan, sehingga mikroalga dan nutrisi tetap dapat tercampur dan tidak terjadi pengendapan mikroalga (Hadiyanto dan Azim, 2012). Kolam sirkuit inilah yang digunakan sebagai kolam atau sawah mikroalga\\\label{b1p3}

    \noindent Pada kolam atau sawah mikroalga terdapat sebuat kincir (\textit{paddle wheel}) yang berfungsi sebagai penggerak aliran. Pada bagian tengah kolam terdapat sebuah dinding melintang sebagai pembatas kedua sisi lintasan dalam kolam. Pada bagian dasar kolam terdapat pula cekungan yang disebut sebagai sump.\\ \label{b1p4}

    \noindent Aliran massa dalam sistem kultivasikolam sirkuit menjadikan distribusi mikroalga pada suatu arah aliran mengalami perubahan dari keadaaan awalnya. Oleh karena itu, perlu ditinjau bagaimana aliran massa dalam sistem kultivasi tersebut selama berlangsungnya pertumbuhan mikroalga.\\

    \noindent Metode numerik adalah teknik matematika yang digunakan untuk memecahkan masalah matematika yang tidak dapat dipecahkan atau sulit untuk diselesaikan secara analitis (Gilat dan Subraham, 2013). Beberapa metode numerik yang umum dipakai adalah Metode iterasi \textit{Jacobi} dan metode iterasi \textit{Gauss-Seidel} yang digunakan sebagai solusi sistem persamaan linear, metode interpolasi dan regresi yang digunakan untuk pencocokan kurva, dan metode beda hingga yang digunakan untuk penyelesaia persamaan diferensial. \\

    \noindent Penelitian ini menawarkan perancangan model matematika aliran massa dalam sistem kultivasi kolam sirkuit pada sawah alga. Model matematika tersebut dibangun berdasarkan fakta-fakta serta asumsi-asumsi yang selanjutnya akan diselesaikan secara dinamik dan dibandingkan secara numerik menggunakan metode beda hingga. Metode tersebut menggunakan perbedaan hingga yang disusun dengan tujuan mengurangi penyelesaian sistem persamaan aljabar. Penampang sawah mikroalga tampak atas digambarkan pada Gambar 1.1. Arah panah menunjukkan arah aliran (Hadiyanto dan Azim,2012) :
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
     \fbox{%
       \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr9cm-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}\centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{gambar1.png}
        \caption{Geometri Kolam Sirkuit} \label{bab1g1}
       \end{minipage}}
    \end{figure}
    \end{subs}
    \section{Rumusan Masalah}
    \begin{subs}
    Berdasarkan latar belakang diatas maka permasalahan dalam penelitian ini dirumuskan sebagai berikut
    \begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item Bagaimana model matematika dari aliran massa dalam sistem kultivasi kolam sirkuit pada mikroalga?
    \item Bagaimana skema numerik numerik model matematika dari aliran fluida tersebut?
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{subs}
    \section{Tujuan Penelitian}
    \begin{subs}
    Adapun tujuan dari dilakukannya penelitian ini yaitu :
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Mendapatkan model matematika ari aliran massa dalam sistem kultivasi kolam sirkuit pada mikroalga
    \item Mendapatkan skema numerik model matematika dari aliran fluida tersebut
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{subs}
    \section{Manfaat Penelitian}
    \begin{subs}
    Manfaat yang diharapkan dari hasil penelitian ini yaitu.
    \begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item Sebagai referensi pemodelan matematika dalam bidang pertanian mikroalga
    \item Sebagai dukungan terhadap pengembangan ilmu matematika terapan
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{subs}
    \section{Asumsi Penelitian}
    \begin{subs}
    Adapun asumsi yang dikemukakan dalam penelitian ini antara lain :
    \begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item Mikroalga, nutrisi dan air larutan tercampur secara homogen.
    \item Faktor energi yang timbul akibat aktivitas disekitar kolam diabaikan, baik faktor suhu maupun energi dari sistem kultivasi.
    \item Fluida bersifat dinamis dan \textit{incompressible}.
    \item Aliran bersifat \textit{Unsteady State}.
    \item Penelitian di fokuskan pada satu fase pertumbuhan mikrolga (fase stagnan)
    \item Faktor iklim diabaikan
    \item Penelitian ini difokuskan pada aliran lapisan batas yang terletak disekitar titik stagnasi bawah $x=0$.
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{subs}
    \section{Batasan Penelitian}
    \begin{subs}
    Penelitian ini memiliki beberapa batasan sebagai berikut :
    \begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item \textit{Sump} pada sistem sirkuit tidak digunakan, model hanya mengkaji sistem sirkuit aliran alga tanpa sump
    \item Hanya terdapat satu dinding pembatas di tengah sawah mikroalga yang memanjang secara horizontal
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{subs}

    \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]