# How to make roman numbering oneside dan arabic numering twoside

Tags: page-numbering

I want to make a thesis like my institute format. And in my institute, the roman numbering is oneside (except tableofcontent) and the arabic numbering is twoside. How to make it? This is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{pslatex}%
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{1pt}
    \usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=215mm,top=3cm,left=4cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Gambar}
    \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabel}

    %\renewcommand{\refname}{Daftar Pustaka}
    %\renewcommand{\bibliname}{Daftar Pustaka}

    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \usepackage{mdframed} \newmdenv[]{kotak} %membuat kotak
    \newenvironment{subs}
      {\adjustwidth{0.935cm}{0pt}}
      {\endadjustwidth}
      \newenvironment{subs2}
        {\adjustwidth{1.28cm}{0pt}}
        {\endadjustwidth}
        \newenvironment{subs3}
                {\adjustwidth{2cm}{0pt}}
                {\endadjustwidth}
    % Membuat seluruh tulisan menjadi Times New Roman.
    \usepackage{pslatex}
    \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{mathtools} \newcommand
    \numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}} %penomoran equation
    \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \hyphenpenalty=10000
    \hbadness=10000
    \tolerance=1
    \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB}                % mengubah "Chapter" jadi "BAB"
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{            %pengaturan awal

    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \center \MakeUppercase{\large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}
    %\chapapp\space memunculkan kata "Bab"
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 6\p@ % Mengatur jarak antara "Bab 1" dan "Pendahuluan"
    \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \large \uppercase{\bfseries #1\par\nobreak} %Bagian ini memunculkan judul bab
    \vskip 30\p@ % Mengatur jarak antara "Bab 1" dengan "Teks"
    }}
    %
    \makeatother                            %pengaturan akhir
    \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

    \titleformat{\section}{\bf\normalsize}{\makebox[1.78em][l]{\thesection}}{1ex}{}{}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\bf\normalsize}
    \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bf\normalsize}
    % Mengatur spacing section

    \titlespacing*{\section}
    {0pt}{24pt}{6pt}
    \titlespacing*{\subsection}
    {0pt}{24pt}{6pt}
    \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
    {0pt}{24pt}{6pt}
    % Untuk mengkustomisasi margin

    \newpagestyle{mainps}{%
    \setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
}


    \usepackage{scrextend}
    % Digunakan untuk mengatur caption dalam dokumen.
    \usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,up,textfont=up]{caption}
    % Untuk menghapus titik dua (colon)
    \captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
    \captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space}
    \usepackage{tocbasic}

    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
    % Redefinition of ToC command to get centered heading
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ISI}\cleardoublepage\null\vspace{-12pt}\hfill\textbf{\large\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
      \vspace{30pt}
      \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
    \makeatother

    \usepackage{eqparbox} %membuat spasi chapter rata

    \usepackage{titletoc}%
    \titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
      [0pt]% <left>
      {\vspace{12pt}\bfseries}% <above-code>
      {\eqmakebox[TC][l]{\chaptername~\thecontentslabel }\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
      {}% <numberless-entry-format>
      {\hfill\contentspage}[\vspace{0pt}]

      \titlecontents{section}[27mm]
        {\vspace{-6pt}\normalsize\normalfont}
        {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{24pt}}{}
        {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}{\contentspage}}

      \titlecontents{subsection}[38mm]
        {\vspace{-6pt}\normalsize\normalfont}
        {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{30pt}}{}
        {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}{\contentspage}}
    %listoffigures
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
    \cleardoublepage
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\listoffigures{{%
      \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
      \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
      \null\vspace{-24pt}\hfill\textbf{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont\listfigurename}\hfill\null\par
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
      \vspace{20pt}

        \@starttoc{lof}%
    }}

    \titlecontents{figure}
      [2.5cm]
      {\addvspace{12pt}}
      {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
          \makebox[2.4cm][l]{Gambar~\thecontentslabel}%
        }%
      }
      {\hspace{-1.7cm}}
      {\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}

    % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275577:
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
      \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    }{}{}{}
    \makeatother

    %listoftables
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
    \cleardoublepage{}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\listoftables{%
      \null\hfill\textbf{\large\listtablename}\hfill\null\par
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
      \vspace{20pt}

        \@starttoc{lot}%
    }
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
    \cleardoublepage{}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\listoffigures{{%
      \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
      \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
      \null\hfill\textbf{\large\listfigurename}\hfill\null\par
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
      \vspace{20pt}

        \@starttoc{lof}%
    }}
    \titlecontents{table}
      [2.5cm]
      {\addvspace{12pt}}
      {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
          \makebox[2.4cm][l]{Tabel~\thecontentslabel}%
        }%
      }
      {\hspace{-1.7cm}}
      {\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
      \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    }{}{}{}
    \makeatother

    \newenvironment{abstract}{
      \vspace*{\fill}
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries\abstractname
      \end{center}}%
      {\vfill}

      \usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
      \addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
    %\fncyfront
    \frontmatter
 \newgeometry{top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm} 
 \begin{titlepage}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN SAMPUL}                                                             %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
                                        %Memanggil gambar, untad.jpg = nama file gambar, width = lebar gambar, height = tinggi gambar
                                                                        %environment akhir gambar
  \vspace{0.5cm}    
                                                                            %memulai rata tengah
\fontsize{14}{12pt} \selectfont {SOLUSI NUMERIK MODEL ALIRAN MASSA\\DALAM SISTEM KULTIVASI \textit{OPEN POND RACEWAYS} PADA SAWAH ALGA}\\
 \end{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{2}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN JUDUL}
 \begin{titlepage}
 \cleardoublepage
 \pagestyle{fancy}

                                                                    %Menghilangkan nomor halaman 
 \centering                                                                                 %rata tengah
                                                                %memulai rata tengah
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
 \end{titlepage}

 \restoregeometry

\setcounter{page}{3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN PERSETUJUAN PEMBIMBING}

\begin{center}
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PERSETUJUAN PEMBIMBING}}}
\end{center}
\vspace{36pt}

\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{HALAMAN PENGESAHAN PENGUJI}

\begin{center}
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PENGESAHAN DEWAN PENGUJI}}}
\end{center}
\vspace{24pt}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ISI}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mainps}
\cleardoublepage
\onehalfspacing

\chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{Latar Belakang}
\newpage
\section{Rumusan Masalah}
\end{document}
```

from `\titlepage` until `\tableofcontent` must be oneside. And from chapter until the last must be twoside.

Comment: I have answered your question abot switching between `oneside` and `twoside` which has to do with the layout of the text on the pages. But perhaps you are talking about printing on one side of the paper versus printing on both sides of the paper. This is up to the printer you use, not LaTeX.

Comment: If you want to alternate numbering styles, [here’s an answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579103/odd-page-one-indocarabic-style-even-page-roman-style/579115#579115)

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer to your question but the following shows how you can change between onesided roman numbered pages and twosided arabic numbered pages.

```
% sideprob.tex  SE 522630 mix of one and twosided
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\textheight}{4in}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setoneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse}
\newcommand{\settwoside}{\@twosidetrue \@mparswitchtrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setoneside
\textbf{One sided roman numbering}

\lipsum[1-6]

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\settwoside
\textbf{Two side arabic numbering}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Use the appropriate macros (`\set...side` and `\pagenumbering{...}` at the appropriate places in your document.